# Circular Reference On C# Properties

Tags: c#

May be this is a newbie question but here it is.
I am developing a card game and i hava a class named Player ...
Player has a property called Partner ( another Player ) and another property called Points.

```
public class Player
{ 
   public Player()
   {
   }
   public Player Partner { get; set; }

   private int points = 0;
   public int Points 
   { 
   get { return points;}
   set { 
       if (Partner != null) Partner.Points = value;
       points = value; 
       } // -> Here is the problem cause p1.Partner = p2 and p2.Partner = p1
   }
```

The question is : How is the most "elegant way" to set the Points property for a player and have its Partner points property set automatically ?

For instance:

```
Player p1 = new Player();
Player p2 = new Player();
p1.Partner = p2;
p2.Partner = p1;
p1.Points = 10;
int p = p2.Points
```

p should be equal to 10.

Thanks in advance ,
Marcelo
Brazil< .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set { 
    points = value; 
    if (Partner != null && Partner.Points != value)
    {
        Partner.Points = value;
    }
}
```

Will fix the circular reference, but having a `Partnership` object that they both refer to get the total points will be cleaner and allows each player to store the individual points they've scored too.

Answer (score 4):

I think I would add a composite (thx @ noah) class "Team".

Team has properties for "Players" and "Points".

```
public class Team
    {
        public Player[] Players { get; set; } //or Player1 and Player2, depends
        public int Points { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the clean way. It's not called 'parent class', though, because that would imply there's inheritance, which shouldn't be used here. This is merely composition.

Comment: @noah1989: Correct, parent not in a parent-way. Container-class? Group-class?

Comment: It's called [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), so it would be a "composite class" and the players would be the components, but we don't use these terms in .NET because _everything_ is an `Object`, so all classes that have members are composite classes.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Points` property off the player class, and move it to a `Game`, `Board`, or `Team` class.

If you had a `Team` class, you probably wouldn't even need a `Partner` property on your `Player`, you'd have a `Team` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following as the first line to your setter:

```
if (points == value && partner.Points == value) return
```

This should stop your infinite recursion.